# PLC to act as or simulate 4-20 mA transducer

Tags: current-measurement, plc

I have a PLC Control system that measures a few 4-20 mA pressure sensors. Today we test these with loop calibrators on each channel.

I want to set up a PLC that simulates these pressure sensors so I can program a complete test, or simulation if you will, of the system.

The PLC system has these 4-20 mA modules:
http://www.bartec.de/homepage/eng/20_produkte/130_automatisierung/s_20_130_90_10.asp?ProdID=204#Docu

If I understand current loops correctly I need a passive 4-20mA output module (and of course I need zener barriers for the Ex/IS).

Question is that I havent seen any passive 4-20 mA output modules, at least not with Profibus or K-bus, and that makes me think that this might be a flawed idea. Anyone care to help me along?

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you need here is a DAC to give 4-20mA output to feed your 4-20m4 inputs.

The more flexible and expensive solution is a real DAC. Usually 0-10V. Simply drive a current amplifier scaled to give a maximum 20mA. The analogue outputs of PLC can sometimes be configured as current sources as well.

The cheaper way is to use a voltage source and series resistors switched by some relays. Unless there is some compelling reason I would use 3 relays and resistors to give me 4mA, 12mA and 20mA sources. (Bottom, Middle and Top of the analogue range to be tested). This catches most issues I've seen in production. The relays can be driven by any suitable digital output of a PLC.

Comment: The loop power is on the device under test. The device I need must sink current.

Comment: In that case the relay and resistor will still work. There would be no grounding issues :-)

Comment: Also you could still use an amplifer driving a transistor or mosfet with a sense resistor on the base, just use the 4-20mA as the source across the mosfet and sense resistor.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop and the links at the bottom of the page. This seems the best description http://www.datel.com/data/meters/dms-an20.pdf

Comment: Sorry mate, this is just too much hazzle. I would need to get the electronic part certified and just documenting it would take most of my budget. And _if_ I were to build something like this, there are more specialised ICs that would do a great job.

Comment: Id go with resistor loads and relays unless you need a total flexable solution. It can be built on din rail next to the PLC simulating the instruments using terminal blocks etc.